# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'result'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to take the highest id and add one to make a new id. When I try to start it (it's at null as nothing is in there yet) it gives me this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'result'`.

```py
@app.route('/new-recipe', methods=['POST'])
def create_recipe(application):
    data = request.get_json()
    current_id = int(db.session.query(func.max(Recipes.id)).first())
    # I've tried without int() too.

    if current_id >= 1:
        new_id = current_id + 1
        new_recipe = Recipes(id=new_id)
        return new_recipe.id
    else:
        new_recipe = Recipes(id=1)
        return new_recipe.id
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program ? For example print out `db.session.query(func.max(Recipes.id)).first()` to see what it is, and you you could get the int you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.scalar()` to convert from a result to a value.

```
current_id = db.session.query(func.max(Recipes.id)).scalar()
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar

I do, however, have a comment on your approach: it would be better to let the database generate the ids for you, because code like yours could behave unpredictably when multiple people are accessing `/new-recipe` at the same time.

If you get the last id and then do an insert in a separate query (while not in a database transaction), someone else can insert a record with the same ID, as the one you're attempting to insert, before you. This would cause an error.

Comment: This was what I needed. Thank you.